# How can I check if my data follows a Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: model-selection, dirichlet-distribution, compositional-data

I have some compositional data, and I intend on using log ratio analysis. However, if my data could be modelled to be Dirichlet distributed, then that might be a more preferable approach. But how do I check that?